# Assign a BigInteger to a normal integer

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

For example, I can do this :

```
uint64_t a = 100;
BigInteger b = a;
```

But I can't do this :

```
BigInteger a = 100;
uint64_t b = a;
```

Is there any way? Thanks.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142588/converting-bits-to-decimal-integer-string-is-so-slow

Comment: @xersi _"Is there any way?"_ You can provide a conversion operator overload for example.

Comment: What is a conversion operator overload?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ , it's possible to overload ```operator=``` for ```uint64_t``` type ?

Comment: @xersi See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/16615725#16615725) please.

Comment: @isnullxbh A conversion operator overload seems to be the more natural way.. In the end the result might be equivalent.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, Yes, you are right !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to make `BigInteger` implicitly convertible to `uint64_t`. This can be achieved with a [conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator):

```
BigInteger::operator uint64_t();
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

```
operator uint64_t() {return get_integer();}
```

Thanks for your help.